# Why I'm getting System.Collections.Generic.List`1[VoltageStablizer.EnterParams+Invoice] instead of list's contents in Wpf

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, combobox, datagrid

[image: Screenshot]

I decided to make a small project about Voltage Stabilizer. I tried to insert data from ComboBox to DataGrid in WPF.

I created Invoice class:

```
public class Invoice
        {
            public string Number { get; set; }
            public string Item { get; set; }
            public string Power { get; set; }
            public string Quantity { get; set; }

        }
```

I using a List to insert information to DataGrid.

```
            List<Invoice> ItemCollection = new List<Invoice>()
            {
                new Invoice() {Number = num, Item = equipment.Text, Power = power.Text, Quantity = quantity.Text}
            };
                DataGrid.Items.Add(ItemCollection);
```

But if I make the equipment, power and quantity ComboBoxex data print out in the DataGrid, I get wrong result:

```
     System.Collections.Generic.List`1[VoltageStablizer.EnterParams+Invoice]
```

Comment: What do you mean by "wrong result"? What's the "correct result"?

Comment: Try replacing ` DataGrid.Items.Add(ItemCollection);` to `DataGrid.ItemSource=ItemCollection'.

Comment: @Orifjon. In my code correct result should be name of electrical equipment. For example user choose equipment name TV, oven or refrigerator and when user click on add button this equipment name should insert to datagrid table.

Comment: @Orifjon. I tried DataGrid.ItemSource=ItemCollection. But this didn't work properly.Every time I choose parameters and click add button, previous information erased. In my project DataGrid must display multiple items which I choosed. When I use DataGrid.Items.Add(ItemCollection) DataGrid display multiple item, however it display System.Collections.Generic.List`1[VoltageStablizer.EnterParams+Invoice] instead of equipment's name which I choosen using ComboBox.

Comment: First and foremost it should be using `DataGrid.ItemsSource` as already noted. Then you can customize the columns instead of auto-generating them, either in Xaml or from code behind. @Jamshid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type of items in `DataGrid.Items` is [DataGridItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datagriditem?view=netframework-4.8.1) Which means you can't directly add another collection with different type.

On the other hand, assigning `IEnumerable` (`ItemCollection` in your case) to  `DataGrid.ItemsSource` automatically generates columns for `DataGrid`.

When adding new item to list, you can just add it to `ItemCollection`. Also create a property in your container for `ItemCollection`, so you can use in different parts of your code.

```
// When initializing your container
ItemCollection = new List<Invoice>(); 
DataGrid.ItemsSource = ItemCollection;

// When add button clicked
ItemCollection.Add(new Invoice() {Number = num, Item = equipment.Text, Power = power.Text, Quantity = quantity.Text});
```